# setAbstractView() prevents mousedown events from propagating to KmlFeatures

Tags: javascript, kml, google-earth-plugin

Using the Google Earth plugin, I want to be able to allow the user to select placemarks on the ground while the camera is moving, but am not sure how this is possible.  It seems that when you call setAbstractView(), even with the flyToSpeed set to SPEED_TELEPORT, the Google Earth plugin ignores any mouse down events except for those to the GEGlobe.

Here's the code, altered slightly (from http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#draggable_placemark) to illustrate my issue:

```
var ge;

var placemark;
var dragInfo = null;
var la;
var lat = 37;
var lon = -122;

google.load("earth", "1");

function init() {
  google.earth.createInstance('map3d', initCallback, failureCallback);
}

function tick() {
  la.set(lat, lon,
    0, // altitude
    ge.ALTITUDE_RELATIVE_TO_GROUND,
    0, // heading
    0, // straight-down tilt
    5000 // range (inverse of zoom)
    );
  ge.getView().setAbstractView(la);
  lon = lon + 0.00000001;
}

function initCallback(instance) {
  ge = instance;
  ge.getWindow().setVisibility(true);

  // add a navigation control
  ge.getNavigationControl().setVisibility(ge.VISIBILITY_AUTO);

  // add some layers
  ge.getLayerRoot().enableLayerById(ge.LAYER_BORDERS, true);
  ge.getLayerRoot().enableLayerById(ge.LAYER_ROADS, true);

  // create the placemark
  placemark = ge.createPlacemark('');

  var point = ge.createPoint('');
  point.setLatitude(lat);
  point.setLongitude(lon);
  placemark.setGeometry(point);

  // add the placemark to the earth DOM
  ge.getFeatures().appendChild(placemark);

  // look at the placemark we created
  la = ge.createLookAt('');
  placemark.setName('Drag Me!');
  ge.getOptions().setFlyToSpeed(ge.SPEED_TELEPORT);
  tick();

  // Comment this next line out and the drag works as expected.
  google.earth.addEventListener(ge, "frameend", tick);

  // listen for mousedown on the window (look specifically for point placemarks)
  google.earth.addEventListener(ge.getWindow(), 'mousedown', function(event) {
    console.log("target type = " + event.getTarget().getType());
    if (event.getTarget().getType() == 'KmlPlacemark' &&
        event.getTarget().getGeometry().getType() == 'KmlPoint') {
      //event.preventDefault();
      var placemark = event.getTarget();

      dragInfo = {
        placemark: event.getTarget(),
        dragged: false
      };
    }
  });

  // listen for mousemove on the globe
  google.earth.addEventListener(ge.getGlobe(), 'mousemove', function(event) {
    if (dragInfo) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var point = dragInfo.placemark.getGeometry();
      point.setLatitude(event.getLatitude());
      point.setLongitude(event.getLongitude());
      dragInfo.dragged = true;
    }
  });

  // listen for mouseup on the window
  google.earth.addEventListener(ge.getWindow(), 'mouseup', function(event) {
    if (dragInfo) {
      if (dragInfo.dragged) {
        // if the placemark was dragged, prevent balloons from popping up
        event.preventDefault();
      }

      dragInfo = null;
    }
  });

  document.getElementById('installed-plugin-version').innerHTML =
    ge.getPluginVersion().toString();
}

function failureCallback(errorCode) {
}
```

​
If you comment out line 56, where tick() is called at each frameend, everything works as in the unaltered code:  you can successfully drag the place mark.  But when line 56 is in, you can't.  So the problem is really with setAbstractView keeping mousedown events from propagating to either the globe or whatever placemark or feature was being clicked.

Any ideas?  Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Just trying to ascertain whether or not it's related to a bug - what browsers display this behaviour?

Comment: I've reproduced it in Safari, Firefox, and Chrome, and encourage anyone else to try it too.  Simply copy and paste the code block into Google Code Playground:  http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#draggable_placemark

Answer (score 0):

The issue isn't caused by the `setAbstractView` method, it is caused because of the repeated calls to the `tick` method via `framend`.

To explain, you have set up the `tick` method as an event handler for the `frameend` event.
Then the tick method updates the view immediately, triggering the `frameend` event, ad infinitum ...

This pattern causes an issue with the browser message loop, in effect it is blocking the other drag events. Think of it like a very tight loop that is causing a deadlock. To work it you can use `setTimeout` with a value of 0 to execute the code. This way the animation won't be processed until all other pending drag messages are processed.

The key part is a the modification to your `tick()` method.

```
function tick() {
  // prevent deadlock
  setTimeout(function () {
    la.set(lat, lon, 0, ge.ALTITUDE_RELATIVE_TO_GROUND, 0, 0, 5000);
    ge.getView().setAbstractView(la);
    lon += 0.00001;
  }, 0);
};
```

Here, I made a fully working example for you http://jsfiddle.net/fraser/JFLaT/

I tested it and it is working in Chrome, IE, Firefox on Windows 8 and Chrome, Safari, Firefox on OSX.